# How to do docker-compose exec via ssh from another server

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I have to execute docker-compose exec via ssh from one server to another. I try to do it with this command

```
ssh -p 22000 -C -i /home/sportlevel/.ssh/id_rsa -l sportlevel 194.58.107.224 'cd /sportlevel/k4fntr && docker-compose exec -T "app" cmposer install'
```

or the same but with make file

```
ssh -p 22000 -C -i /home/sportlevel/.ssh/id_rsa -l sportlevel 194.58.107.224 'cd /sportlevel/k4fntr && make install'
```

but in the both cases got an error

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"cmposer\": executable file not found
>   in $PATH": unknown

At the same time if i do this command inside second server I have no problems

Comment: Should `cmposer` have a second `o` in it?  Why isn't this "install" command in your image's `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Omg bro you have saved my day